# set and clear interval multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the first slide of my slider I've got some text that changes within an interval.
This is the jQuery to do this:

```
<script>
    var x = 0;
   var text = ["STRATEGICALLY", "COST-EFFECTIVELY", "EFFICIENTLY", "EXCEPTIONALLY"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("banner-change");

var intervalID = setInterval(change, 1500);

function change() {

  jQuery(elem).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    jQuery(elem).text(text[counter++]);

    if (counter >= text.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    jQuery(elem).fadeIn('fast');

       if (++x === 5) {
       window.clearInterval(intervalID);
   }
  });

}

    </script>
```

The slider looks something like this (The shortened code):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="hp-top carousel fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"><img src="" alt="Chicago"/><div class="carousel-caption">
<div class="carousel-caption-inner">
<p class="slider-text small"><span class="slider-padding">What makes</span> us <span class="slider-green">specialists?</span></p>
<p class="slider-text">We just do ip</p>
<p class="slider-text"><span id="banner-change" class="slider-green">exceptionally</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So the words in `<span id="banner-change" class="slider-green">` keep changing. This works fine. However, it only works for the first time the first banner is shown. Which makes sense as I'm clearing the interval as each word is only supposed to show once, but not sure how to do this so that every time the first banner shows it starts the interval again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the carousel evelts to trigger action.
`e.relatedTarget` will then refer to the slide, that is sliding into view.
So if you give it a unique id, you can identify it and run whatever action afterwards.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget.id === 'firstSlide') // do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to stop the whole interval working when I tried this though